# Create JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, phpmyadmin

Hy guys and girls :). Here is my problem.
I have two tables in database(users and comments). One user can post 1 or more comments. I want to retreive data from database in JSON format. When I retrive data, I get format like this

```
[{"username":"kurtMarko","message":"Kako si mama"},{"username":"kurtMarko","message":"kako si tata"},{"username":"kurtMarko","message":"kako si brate"},{"username":"kurtMarko","message":"kako si sestro"}]
```

but I want to retrive data like

```
[{"username":"kurtMarko","message":[{"Kako si mama"},{"kako si tata"},{"kako si brate"},{"kako si sestro"}]]
```

Do you have any idea, suggestions. Every comment will help me. Thank you very much.
Here is my code

```
require("config.inc.php");
$query = "SELECT comments.message, users.username
            FROM comments
            LEFT JOIN users ON users.username = comments.username";

try {

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute();

} catch(PDOException $ex){

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
    die(json_encode($response));

}

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
if ($rows) {
    $response   = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $post["username"]= $row["username"];
        $post["message"] = $row["message"];
        array_push($response, $post);
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Post Available!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
```

Comment: `{"Kako si mama"},{"kako si tata"}` it is not a json and you can not create it by `json_encode`. Only by direct manipulation with the string.

Comment: @Cheery Good catch. He probably meant `"Kako si mama","kako si tat"` as a elements of a string array, and not as objects. OP can you confirm/deny?

Comment: JSON requires a {key:value} pair, so {key} is invalid. I would have your strings in an array only, as such: `["Kako si mama","kako si tata", "kako si brate", "kako si sestro"]`. A json library should be able to do that for you.

Comment: could value `["Kako si mama","kako si tata", "kako si brate", "kako si sestro"]` be json with key message. If I put `$post["message"] = array()` insted `$post["message"] = $row["message"]`, then put foreach loop, i get what I want, but then I get as many as I have usernames in database. Is there solution to get only one username with all messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make different array for that like this below:

```
$response   = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $response[$row["username"]]['message'][] = $row["message"]
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Maybe you have to initialize for the first

Comment: Looks good, but what if I want JSONArray where I will have for every message key for that message? Now it prints `"message":"message":["Kako si mama","kako si tata","kako si brate","kako si sestro"]`. What you will change in code to print `"messages:[{"message":"Kako si mama"},{"message":"kako si tata"},{"message":"kako si brate"},{"message":"kako si sestro"}]`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: As you can see here: http://ideone.com/fork/Mx3qGq, it's work, maybe there is something different in your $rows array, use print_r() to check out!

Answer (score 0):

Your desired DB structure makes this difficult. Since username isn't a key in the array, you'd have to repeatedly search the entire array to find WHERE a particular username is, just so you can append a new message under that user. Why not have this instead:

```
$arr = array();
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $user = $row['username'];
    $msg = $row['message'];
    $arr[$user][] = $msg;
}
```

That would give you:

```
Array (
    'Fred' => array('msg1', 'msg2', 'msg3');
    'Susie' => array('msg4', 'msg5', ....)
);
```

Comment: returns null. Somthing like [].

Answer (score 0):

To be honest with you the first version you don't like is actually the better one.

You want to group records by objects.

If the values are repeated its not a problem it does not hurt.

It might be tempting to shorten your `JSON` string by removing redundant values but this will make it more difficult to manipulate your object.

This is the whole point of json (JavaScript **Object** Notation), in your example each comment represent an object and that's a perfect object graph, don't modify it.